# Storing Vs Calling Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

My application queries Google Geocoding API once per user.
It stores their lat lon for analysis later.

I am considering a feature which calls Google Places API, and shows the user some "Places"
near them, on a map.
I do not want to store nearby Google Places. There is considerable overhead in this process.

Many people, on message boards, stress the importance of not bombarding the Places API from within my application. However, Google Places API allows a huge volume of daily traffic, much higher than Maps API and much higher than my website will use.

Can anyone definitively settle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible reason to stress reducing the number of calls to the Places API is if you may be in danger of exceeding the stated quota limits[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/index#Limits) (currently set at 100,000 for licensed sites). If you are confident that you will not approach or exceed the limit, then your assessment is correct. The added overhead associated with attempting to store results as a way to avoid similar Places API requests is not worth the added complexity. Simply call the Places API, process the results, and then place them on your Google Map to display to your user(s).